# Set entityManager components.xml seam weblogic

Tags: java, persistence, seam, weblogic-10.x

I develop an application with Seam 2.2.0 on weblogic 10.3

In my components.xml, when I set my entityManager, I do this:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
        auto-create="true" persistence-unit-jndi-name="OSSPortailDataSource" />
```

My DataSource is configured like this on weblogic:

JNDI name: OSSPortailDataSource
Driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.18.98:1522:ossi

Now, when I run my application, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
```

Here is the log:

```
16:26:11,646 WARN  [SeamLoginModule] Error invoking login method
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:339)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Expressions$2.invoke(Expressions.java:175)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.jaas.SeamLoginModule.login(SeamLoginModule.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:703)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:575)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.authenticate(Identity.java:344)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.authenticate(Identity.java:332)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.Identity.login(Identity.java:259)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:248)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3502)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2092)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:241)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.initEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:78)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManager(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2249)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.unwrap(Component.java:2275)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2041)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1977)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstanceInAllNamespaces(Component.java:2349)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getValueToInject(Component.java:2301)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.injectAttributes(Component.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.inject(Component.java:1554)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at completel.oss.ossportail.session.Authenticator_$$_javassist_seam_6.authenticate(Authenticator_$$_javassist_seam_6.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
```

How do I configure the persistence to work fine ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

In the components.xml, add the following property:

```
<persistence:entity-manager-factory name="entityManagerFactory"
        persistence-unit-name="OSSPortail" />
```

It's a "link" to the persistence.xml (hibernate configuration).

In the components.xml, modify the managed-persistence-context property:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
    auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{entityManagerFactory}" />
```

Just add the entity-manager-factory attribute which is the name of the persistence:entity-manager-factory property.

Finally, configure the persistence.xml file. Mine is here:

```
<persistence-unit name="OSSPortail" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>OSSPortailDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
            value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="SI" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
            value="OSSPortailDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```